# Should one or multiple controller_manager nodes be used for modular robots (e.g. base + arm)? [ros2_control]

Tags: ros, ros2, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a robot composed of several sub-robots (e.g. a mobile base platform with a manipulator attached), each of which has its own independent controllers defined, is there a preferred approach to managing the controllers for the combination?

Are there reasons *for* or *against* either:

- aggregating the controllers for both the base and arm into a single `controller_manager` node, or
- running separate `controller_manager` nodes for each sub-robot (e.g. `base_controller_manager` and `arm_controller_manager`)?

I'd imagine the former might have a bit less overhead, but the latter might make lifecycle management a bit more flexible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403218/should-one-or-multiple-controller_manager-nodes-be-used-for-modular-robots-(e.g.-base-+-arm)?-%5Bros2_control%5D/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1567 on 2022-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are some things to think about:

- If everything is included in one `controller_manager`, then all controllers will spin at the same rate. That may or may not be OK. The spin rate is determined by the `update_rate` [parameter](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_resources/blob/ros2/panda_moveit_config/config/ros2_controllers.yaml).
- If you have 2 `controller_managers`, then using the command line for querying controller stuff gets more tricky. You can't use `ros2 control list_controllers`, for example -- IIRC you have to specify which controller manager.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2022-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2022-07-01**:
great points, thank you!